# Working with young developers

Tags: colleagues, open-plan

At this point in my life, I have found myself working side-by-side with developers much, much younger than myself.  While I can "take them on" at any time professionally, I am unable to establish any rapport with them.

When I return from a break and enter the open-plan office, they immediately turn down the music that they've been listening to (pretty loudly, I might add) when I was out.  They play networked computer games among themselves during business hours.  This is a branch office, and there is no manager on premises.  There is an office administrator, but she does not actively manage and in any case, is unaware of what's going on because her office is elsewhere in the building.

I would appreciate hearing about coping mechanisms from others who may have had similar experiences.

Comment: What aspect do you need to cope with? Does their behavior interfere with your work? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: are you their manager ?

Comment: (Waiting for the corresponding "Working with old developers" question. "When he returns from a break, we have to silence our music and put our phones away. He says he can't work with all the distractions.")

Comment: Are they doing the same work as you?  Do you all report to the same manager?

Comment: I suspect that your question contains multiple sub questions, but since you're not telling us what those are, I'll take your inital question at face value. Ask one or two of them if they'd be willing to teach you how to play the networked game after 5 or 6 PM (or during lunch, or on a Friday afternoon).

Comment: @StephanBranczyk I really am not interested in playing those games, during or after work hours.

Comment: @shoover     :)))))))))

Comment: @NoloProblemo Yes, and we all report to the same person who is about 7 or 8 years older than them.

Comment: @Neuromancer No, I am not their manager.  Are you asking this as a sarcastic question? Couldn't tell.

Comment: @SrEngineer, I believe Neuromancer is asking because your situation is very different when comparing being their manager vs being their peer.

Comment: @cdkMoose Right, but in my question I state "This is a branch office, and there is no manager on premises."

Comment: @SrEngineer, So do you have a problem with them playing loud music when you're not there? And do you have a problem with them playing games during work hours? Is their productivity (or your productivity) suffering because of their behavior? I have to ask because you haven't really told us what the problem was (except for the fact that you don't have a close rapport with them).

Comment: @StephanBranczyk I think I am old fashioned. :)  I have a problem with playing games during work hours.  Is this acceptable elsewhere?  I am asking because apart from what I have seen on Silicon Valley tv show, I don't know how it is in other companies. And thank you for your interest..

Comment: @SrEngineer, Don't get me wrong. I just wanted to make your complaints explicit and perhaps even rank them in their relative order of importance. You're not the only one with this problem, if you read the reviews of Pandora on glassdoor for example, you'll find that some engineers find the constant concerts on Fridays and the alcohol that's consumed by fellow employees super distracting. And a friend of mine who worked for a bartender related mobile payment application startup was chagrined to find out that the CEO of his company was always drunk and couldn't focus on anything.

Comment: @StephanBranczyk  I really appreciate your comments.  BTW, when I worked at AT&T BL, you couldn't have alcohol on premises, period.  PS: Just saw you're in Alameda! :)  Lived/worked there for three years.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You might want to start by treating them as co-workers and peers rather than someone you need to "take on" or "cope with".

Just treat them as you would anyone else. Be friendly and helpful. Respect them and expect respect in return.

And stop worrying about whatever games they play. Do your work and let their managers/supervisors worry about how much work they do or don't do.

Comment: Thanks, your answer put things in perspective for me.  I respect them, but the reason I don't get respect back - I think - is because they are young and don't know any better.  If I can give an example: during video conference calls, they just block the camera, and I am all the way in the back, not visible.  By nature, I am not socially aggressive, so I just stay back until someone on the call asks where I am, and I wave my hand from the back.  This has happened several times.

Comment: @SrEngineer asking if you can be included in the picture isn't "socially aggressive"